# <kbd> elements are not hidden in a spoilers block

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, spoilers, markdown

Recently noticed the following:

> The catchphrase <kbd>"Danger, Will Robinson!"</kbd> originates with the series, but was only ever used once in it.

Is it intentional to have `<kbd>` text visible inside spoilers markdown?

---

**Image for future reference:**
[image: kbd showing in spoilers]

Comment: Considering its hidden for me while using the app, I'd venture to say that it is, indeed, a bug.

Comment: This affects other SO sites. Have also asked on META: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298674/kbd-elements-are-not-hidden-in-a-spoilers-block